# Photoshop: Preview image with paper white?

Tags: photoshop, printing

In the print dialog in Photoshop, there is an option for showing a simulated paper white in the little print preview.  Can I get the same preview effect in the fullsize regular workspace?

Comment: Hi erjiang. Welcome to photo.se.com! Because it's not really photography specific, I suspect your question may be a better fit over at graphicdesign.se.com so I'm recommending that we move your question there.

Comment: I also flagged this as offtopic, but provided an answer meanwhile.

Comment: This is an on topic question. Printing a photo from Photoshop is a key step in the digital photographic workflow. I need to make this clear, as we have had a variety of off-topic votes on on-topic photoshop questions: Discussing *Photoshop in relation to Photography* IS on topic. That includes *printing photos*. Soft-proofing, which this question pertains to, is a key factor of printing photos.

Comment: No need to be a D-Bag about it...

Comment: @Jay Lance Photography: You should probably give a correct URL when directing people to another SE.

Comment: @Jay: Apologies, not trying to be a douche, its just getting a little exhausting dealing with a considerably higher level of mod requests lately. Having to deal with and increasing number of complaints about on-topic requests is just compounding the work level.

Comment: @jrista: No harm, no foul. Hopefully the impending moderator elections will add a few more mods to the mix and help even out the workload? After all, we're probably not going to be getting any smaller. :-)

Comment: Aye, we do indeed need some more mods. There are at lest 2 mod requests a day, and we've had days where there are 6 or more, and the resolutions are not always straitforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your options in `View` → `Proof Setup` → `Custom...`
You can tune the display options there.

[image: Customize Proof Condition]

To quickly toggle color proofing on/off choose `View` → `Proof Colors`. You could also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> **or** <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.